# How to make 3 states using bootstrap collapse

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have my button do open and summary state then a close button will close it.

First click will open in a summary (like maybe a specific height just to show the summary) and on the second click will full open the div and then a separate button/link to close them:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    link to open/summary
</a>
<a class="pull-right" href="#">close button here</a>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
      This is My summary section
      <br><br><br>
      if you see this then its a fully opened state
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a non-working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6247/) here to play around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that functionality is not supported by the collapse plug-in of the bootstrap. 
Instead some custom coding is required. I approached the problem with creating two buttons and adding specific on click handlers. Also  added an inner collapsible element to be controlled from the second button. The second button Text is changed in dependence of a data attribute that keeps track of the second button state check the snippet :

```js
$('#summaryBtn').on('click',function(e){
    $this = $(e.target);
    $this.addClass('hidden');
    $('#moreBtn').removeClass('hidden');
});
$('#close').on('click', function(){
     $('#collapseExample, #collapseExample > .collapse').collapse('hide');
    $('#moreBtn').addClass('hidden');
    $('#summaryBtn').removeClass('hidden');
});
$('#moreBtn').on('click', function(e){
    $this = $(e.target);
    isMore = $this.data('more');
    var thisText = (isMore) ? 'Less... ' : 'More... ';    
    $this.empty().text(thisText);
    $this.data('more', !isMore);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="summaryBtn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        link to open/summary
    </a>
    <a class="hidden btn btn-primary" id="moreBtn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#more" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="more" data-more="true">
        More... 
    </a>
    <a class="pull-right" id="close" href="#">close button here</a>
    
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
      <div class="well">
          This is My summary section
          <div class="collapse" id="more">
          if you see this then its a fully opened state
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi mzografski, I have here a fiddle with your code in it but modified it, could this be possible? https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6322/

Comment: You can do it if you separate the list in two and the second list is set inside  the inner collapsible element -  in my code that is the `<div class="collapse" id="more" >....</div>`.  https://jsfiddle.net/mzografski/vp6k4aqp/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can add another collapse content inside with a `read more` link.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    link to open/summary
</a>    

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
      This is My summary section
     <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseSummaryExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse?SummaryExample">
  Read More...
</a><div class="collapse" id="collapseSummaryExample">
      <a class="pull-right close" href="#">[x]</a>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    if you see this then its a fully opened state
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('a.close').on('click', function(){
   $('.collapse').collapse('hide')
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6255/)

Comment: hello, thanks but It should be only one button to do that open and summary, still searching for a way

Comment: I guess then you need to write it manually than use bootstrap collapse as when you click the anchor twice the content will collapse.